# Node JS Middleware Function Required

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

When I run the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const routes = require("./routes.js");

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(routes);

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port);
```

I get:

```
TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function.
```

The console says the error occurs at the u in `app.use(routes);`. However if I run:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var clientSessions = require('client-sessions');

var routes = require("./routes");

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/', express.static('./'));
app.use('/js', express.static('./public/js'));
app.use('/CSS', express.static('./public/CSS'));
app.use('/images', express.static('./public/images'));
app.use('/views', express.static('./public/views'));


app.use(clientSessions({
   secret: 'ugkgdiuwgbkbgjwjkgvo'
}));

app.use(routes);

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port);
```

From a different project, that project works fine which leads me to believe there is something wrong with my current project.

However I cannot figure out what. I've tried looking at several other problems similar to mine but none of their solutions helped. Thanks in advance!

routes.js (following a request by @31piy):

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/signup",function(request,response){
    response.sendFile(__dirname + "/Client/HTML/signup.html");
});
router.post("/signup",function(request,response){

});
router.get("/login",function(request,response){
    response.sendFile(__dirname + "/Client/HTML/login.html");
});
```

Comment: Please post the code of `./routes.js`.

Comment: @31piy updated question with routes code. Thanks

Comment: Check the difference of `./routes` with your `./routes.js`. You're not exporting anything from the latter. Since you're not exporting, the code is not being considered as a middleware.

Comment: @31piy I still get the error regardless of having .js or not... I forgot to add the module export at the end, thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export the “router” from routes.js in order for it to work.

In your case add this line at the end of routes.js 
module.exports = router;

That way app.use would be using an actual instance of router.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a router function in different js file
It is needed to be exported so that your app.js can use it.
 module.exports=router
This will help